# Ubuntu boot problem

Tags: installation

Hi all i have new Pacard bell LV44HC intel i3-2350M video Nvidia GT 710m. After boot from usb or cd i can't see anything but laptop still work and load Linux. I try with different distributions but have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close "SECURE BOOT" in **BIOS**. New computers will have this function. I hope it will help you.